# The Reaping alternate soundtrack

Tags: soundtrack, the-reaping

I liked the film 'The Reaping'. However, the [John Frizell soundtrack](http://www.allmusic.com/album/the-reaping-original-motion-picture-soundtrack-mw0000746656) seemed a safe choice compared to the usually suspenseful work of [Philip Glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Reaping#Score) which was rejected for some reason. Why was the original soundtrack rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [interview](http://www.soundtrack.net/content/article/?id=216) with Philip Glass regarding *The Reaping* suggests reasons that the soundtrack may have been rejected (his expertise was in character films rather than action, and the direction of the film kept changing):

> What was your musical approach to this film?
>
> Oh it was quite different. These kinds of films are more about action
>   instead of character, if I can put it that way. With Notes on a
>   Scandal, you're talking about interpersonal dynamics - they're very
>   delicate, and profoundly dramatic and challenging and exhausting in a
>   way. With The Reaping and Candyman, for that matter, you're talking
>   about events which you can't really explain, and can't be explained by
>   character - they have nothing to do with character! You're talking
>   about music that works more with the surface of the action than with
>   the depths of the character. It's a very different way of working, and
>   I had to learn how to do it.
>
> When I was doing more abstract theater pieces, there are similarities
>   with working on those and horror films. Wouldn't it be funny to
>   compare doing a Beckett play and doing a slasher film? But it's true!
>   You're working with more abstract ideas with these kinds of films. I'm
>   putting it the way I experience working on it, and I've found that
>   horror movies are more difficult to do. They're more challenging for
>   me, and I find them very interesting. So I enjoyed working on Taking
>   Lives. I liked the director, and I liked the performances and it was a
>   very interesting film to work on. I felt that was true of The Reaping
>   too. It was a long process because, again, it was a film where the
>   director (Stephen Hopkins) really began to understand the film as they
>   were making it. There were whole sections re-shot, people re-cast, and
>   things were being changed all along. It was a film that was a voyage
>   of discovery, there's no question.

Glass is known for self-plagiarizing, and I have found a [review](http://philipglass.typepad.com/glass_notes/2010/03/a-premiere-and-an-homage.html) suggesting that he used some of the rejected material in his 2007 opera *Appomattox*, which might explain why we are not finding recordings of the score or copies of the film with that score.